# Why is "Time Was" by Wishbone Ash considered progressive rock?

Tags: genre, genre-characteristics, prog-rock

#### Some characteristics of prog that it seems to be missing:

- **Very long songs and solos**

  - ✅Okay, so it's almost 10 minutes long, I'll give it that.
- **More jazz or classical influences than blues**

  - ❌*Time Was* is very bluesy, and it doesn't seem jazzy or classical to me, but I'm not a musician
- **Incorporating classical and electronic instrumentation**

  - ❌Not at all!
- **Fantasy or otherwise story lyrics**

  - ❌maybe a little, but certainly not much

#### And yet [the song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I258PZwAPkk) seems to be classified as prog. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [wikipedia entry for prog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_rock). Folk elements, or blending of influences, and complicated arrangements are also part of the prog thing.  The twelve-string intro, CSNY-type harmonies....then a more full-tilt blues-rock section, bluesy guitar solo, power chords and so on - it's quite a complicated song.  I know what you mean with your question - I'm of that era and I would not immediately put this song in the prog-rock bucket like King Crimson or Jethro Tull - but then again, the fact that it has different sections in different styles, I could imagine either of those two bands doing this song too...

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Thank you :) (also I like your edits to my question, but there's no  way to upvote an edit)